# Could not get connection while getPartitionedTopicMetadata - io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out

Tags: apache-pulsar

I have a basic Pulsar app, and when I try to connect to Pulsar, I get this exception:

> 2021-03-10 14:38:26.107  WARN 7 --- [r-client-io-1-1]
> o.a.pulsar.client.impl.ConnectionPool    : Failed to open connection
> to my-pulsar-server-ms-tls.domain.com:6651 :
> io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out:
> my-pulsar-server-ms-tls.domain.com/10.80.13.38:6651 2021-03-10
> 14:38:26.212  WARN 7 --- [al-listener-3-1]
> o.a.pulsar.client.impl.PulsarClientImpl  : [topic:
> persistent://myTenant/myNamespace/myTopic]
> Could not get connection while getPartitionedTopicMetadata -- Will try
> again in 100 ms

My Pulsar client is pretty basic:

```
PulsarClient.builder()
     .serviceUrl(serviceUrl)
     .authentication(AuthenticationFactory.token(authToken))
     .tlsTrustCertsFilePath(serverCertificateFilePath.toString())
     .enableTlsHostnameVerification(false)
     .allowTlsInsecureConnection(false)
     .build();
```

The producer is also pretty basic and looks like this:

```
pulsarClient.newProducer(Schema.STRING)
            .topic(topic)
            .create();
```

I've verified that the token and TLS cert are correct. I've also tried connecting a consumer *from this same environment* and got a similar exception, and I know that others with the same code are able to connect to the same Pulsar cluster from other environments. What is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your connection is getting blocked by a firewall or network issue.
Verify that you can establish a connection to your endpoint `my-pulsar-server-ms-tls.domain.com:6651` from your environment.

If you're able to run a network packet dump (like tcpdump), that should make it obvious if you're not able to establish a connection.

You can also try running `curl my-pulsar-server-ms-tls.domain.com:6651`, and if you get back some html, that means you were able to reach the server. However, if you get `Could not resolve host`, then you were blocked by the network configuration (such as a missing route) or firewall.